# SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

Would it be possible to construct SQL to concatenate column values from
multiple rows?

The following is an example:

Table A

```
PID
A
B
C
```

Table B

```
PID   SEQ    Desc

A     1      Have
A     2      a nice
A     3      day.
B     1      Nice Work.
C     1      Yes
C     2      we can 
C     3      do 
C     4      this work!
```

Output of the SQL should be -

```
PID   Desc
A     Have a nice day.
B     Nice Work.
C     Yes we can do this work!
```

So basically the Desc column for out put table is a concatenation of the SEQ values from Table B?

Any help with the SQL?

Comment: See for example: http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html

Comment: Please look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348687/2459039). It will be useful to you.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

There are a few ways depending on what version you have - see the [oracle documentation on string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php). A very common one is to use [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT pid, LISTAGG(Desc, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) AS description
FROM B GROUP BY pid;
```

Then join to `A` to pick out the `pids` you want.

**Note:** Out of the box, `LISTAGG` only works correctly with `VARCHAR2` columns.

Comment: using wm_concat() for Oracle 10g concatenates the text in the ascending order of the sequence number delimited by commas, can we make descending delimited by something else?

Answer (score 22):

There's also an `XMLAGG` function, which works on versions prior to 11.2. Because `WM_CONCAT` is [undocumented and unsupported by Oracle](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm), it's recommended not to use it in production system.

With `XMLAGG` you can do the following:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,ename||',')).EXTRACT('//text()') "Result" 
FROM employee_names
```

What this does is

- put the values of the `ename` column (concatenated with a comma) from the `employee_names` table in an xml element (with tag E)
- extract the text of this
- aggregate the xml (concatenate it)
- call the resulting column "Result"

Comment: XMLAGG works on Oracle 12.2. Moreover, XLMAGG allows to concatanate very long strings which LISTAGG may not because of their final length.

Answer (score 14):

With SQL model clause:

```
SQL> select pid
  2       , ltrim(sentence) sentence
  3    from ( select pid
  4                , seq
  5                , sentence
  6             from b
  7            model
  8                  partition by (pid)
  9                  dimension by (seq)
 10                  measures (descr,cast(null as varchar2(100)) as sentence)
 11                  ( sentence[any] order by seq desc
 12                    = descr[cv()] || ' ' || sentence[cv()+1]
 13                  )
 14         )
 15   where seq = 1
 16  /

P SENTENCE
- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A Have a nice day
B Nice Work.
C Yes we can do this work!

3 rows selected.
```

I wrote about this [here](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/05/string-aggregation-with-model-clause.html). And if you follow the link to the OTN-thread you will find some more, including a performance comparison.

Answer (score 11):

The **LISTAGG** analytic function was introduced in ***Oracle 11g Release 2***, making it very easy to aggregate strings.
If you are using 11g Release 2 you should use this function for string aggregation.
Please refer below url for more information about string concatenation.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

[String Concatenation](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php)

Answer (score 9):

As most of the answers suggest, `LISTAGG` is the obvious option. However, one annoying aspect with `LISTAGG` is that if the total length of concatenated string exceeds 4000 characters( limit for `VARCHAR2` in SQL ), the below error is thrown, which is difficult to manage  in Oracle versions upto 12.1

> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

A new feature added in 12cR2 is the `ON OVERFLOW` clause of `LISTAGG`.
The query including this clause would look like:

```
SELECT pid, LISTAGG(Desc, ' ' on overflow truncate) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) AS desc
FROM B GROUP BY pid;
```

The above will restrict the output to 4000 characters but will not throw the  `ORA-01489` error.

These are some of the additional options of `ON OVERFLOW` clause:

- `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE 'Contd..'`  :  This will display `'Contd..'` at
  the end of string (Default is `...` )
- `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE ''`  :   This will display the 4000 characters
  without any terminating string.
- `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE  WITH COUNT` : This will display the total
  number of characters at the end after the terminating characters.
  Eg:- '`...(5512)`'
- `ON OVERFLOW ERROR` : If you expect the `LISTAGG` to fail with the
  `ORA-01489` error ( Which is default anyway ).

Answer (score 7):

For those who must solve this problem using Oracle 9i (or earlier), you will probably need to use SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, since LISTAGG is not available.

To answer the OP, the following query will display the PID from Table A and concatenate all the DESC columns from Table B:

```
SELECT pid, SUBSTR (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (description, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY pid, seq) rnum, pid, description
       FROM (
              SELECT a.pid, seq, description
              FROM table_a a, table_b b
              WHERE a.pid = b.pid(+)
             )
      )
START WITH rnum = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1 AND PRIOR pid = pid
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY pid;
```

There may also be instances where keys and values are all contained in one table. The following query can be used where there is no Table A, and only Table B exists:

```
SELECT pid, SUBSTR (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (description, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY pid, seq) rnum, pid, description
       FROM (
              SELECT pid, seq, description
              FROM table_b
             )
      )
START WITH rnum = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1 AND PRIOR pid = pid
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY pid;
```

All values can be reordered as desired. Individual concatenated descriptions can be reordered in the PARTITION BY clause, and the list of PIDs can be reordered in the final ORDER BY clause.

---

**Alternately:** there may be times when you want to concatenate all the values from an entire table into one row.

The key idea here is using an artificial value for the group of descriptions to be concatenated.

In the following query, the constant string '1' is used, but any value will work:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (description, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY pid, seq) rnum, description
       FROM (
              SELECT '1' unique_id, b.pid, b.seq, b.description
              FROM table_b b
             )
      )
START WITH rnum = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1;
```

Individual concatenated descriptions can be reordered in the PARTITION BY clause.

Several other answers on this page have also mentioned this extremely helpful reference:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Answer (score 6):

1. LISTAGG delivers the best performance if sorting is a must(00:00:05.85)

   `SELECT pid, LISTAGG(Desc, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) AS description
   FROM B GROUP BY pid;`
2. COLLECT delivers the best performance if sorting is not needed(00:00:02.90):

   `SELECT pid, TO_STRING(CAST(COLLECT(Desc) AS varchar2_ntt)) AS Vals FROM B GROUP BY pid;`
3. COLLECT with ordering is bit slower(00:00:07.08):

   `SELECT pid, TO_STRING(CAST(COLLECT(Desc ORDER BY Desc) AS varchar2_ntt)) AS Vals FROM B GROUP BY pid;`

All other techniques were slower.

Comment: It would be helpful to elaborate on your answer.

Comment: John, l didn't wanted to repeat from the article but in short these are the results:
1. LISTAGG delivers the best performance if sorting is a must(00:00:05.85)

2. COLLECT delivers the best performance if sorting is not needed(00:00:02.90):
 SELECT pid, 
            TO_STRING(CAST(COLLECT(Desc) AS varchar2_ntt)) AS Vals
  FROM B
GROUP BY pid;    
3. COLLECT with ordering is bit slower(00:00:07.08):
SELECT pid,
            TO_STRING(CAST(COLLECT(Desc ORDER BY Desc) AS varchar2_ntt)) AS Vals
  FROM B
GROUP BY pid;
All other techniques were slower.

Comment: You can just edit your answer to include relevant information.

Comment: I was too late in the edit and that is why I added it again. Sorry I am new here and just starting to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run a select query, run this:

`SET SERVEROUT ON SIZE 6000`

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,SUPLR_SUPLR_ID||',')).EXTRACT('//text()') "SUPPLIER" 
FROM SUPPLIERS;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
 SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,fieldname||',')).EXTRACT('//text()') "FieldNames"
    FROM FIELD_MASTER
    WHERE FIELD_ID > 10 AND FIELD_AREA != 'NEBRASKA';
```

Answer (score -3):

In the select where you want your concatenation, call a SQL function.

For example:

```
select PID, dbo.MyConcat(PID)
   from TableA;
```

Then for the SQL function:

```
Function MyConcat(@PID varchar(10))
returns varchar(1000)
as
begin

declare @x varchar(1000);

select @x = isnull(@x +',', @x, @x +',') + Desc
  from TableB
    where PID = @PID;

return @x;

end
```

The Function Header syntax might be wrong, but the principle does work.

Comment: This is invalid for Oracle