# Concatenating multiple results of a query in one row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have 2 tables with one having a reference to the first by id

first table for example is customer having the fields

```
    id       firstname     lastname
    ------   ---------     ---------
    1        john          smith
    2        jessica       james
```

the second table for example is product having the fields

```
   id        customer_id     product     descr
   -------   -----------     ---------   ------
   1         1               ts          Shirt
   2         1               ti          Tie
   3         2               sk          skrit
```

I need a query that will output the following

```
   customer.firstname  customer.lastname    product_and_desc
   ------------------  ------------------   ---------------------
   john                smith                ts-Shirt , ti-Tie
   jessica             james                sk-skirt
```

with the product rows variable for each customer.

I appreciate you help :)

thanks,

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: Hi, oracle version 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows

Comment: was just trying it and it worked :) not sure if I should keep the question, seems like I didn't do my research well before posting :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list_agg()`.  In your case:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname,
       list_agg(p.product||'-'||p.desc, ' , ') within group (order by p.id) as product_and_desc
from customer c join
     product p
     on c.id = p.customer_id
group by c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

I would suggest, though, that the second argument to `list_agg()` be ', ' rather than ' , '.  The space before the comma looks a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

```
select first_name,last_name,wm_concat(product||'-'||descr) as product_and_descr
from tbl1 ,tbl2 where tbl1.id=tbl2.customer_id
group by first_name,last_name;
```