# Append two rows into one (that differs on one colum)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query that returns a single row for each unique ID in my oracle table. 
The problem is that i have one column, Description, that isnt unique in each row (Description-column is the only coulmn that can differ for each ID row btw). This is what my table looks like:

```
ID              Description       Customer         
==================================================
5119450733      Cost              GOW_1
5119450733      Price             GOW_1
1543512377      Cost              GOW_2
```

Is there a way to query the table so that i append the results from Description so that i can have unique id rows? for example like this:

```
ID              Description       Customer         
==================================================
5119450733      Cost,Price        GOW_1
1543512377      Cost              GOW_2
```

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` function if you are using `Oracle 11g Release 2`.

```
SELECT Id, 
       listagg(Description,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY description) AS Description, 
       Customer 
FROM   <table_name>
GROUP BY id, customer;
```

Refer the below link to know more about [String Aggregation Techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) on different versions.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this function was introduced in 11gR2.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin, Yeah. You are right. I've mention that in my answer. Thanks.!