# Display columns from multiple rows in single row oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data returned from from one my sql like

```
node_no  code  value1  order
100       AB     001     1
100       AB     007     2
101       AB     010     3
```

I have to further process this data using sql, to get output like

```
node_no   code  value1  value2
100        AB     001     007
101        AB     010     null
```

The requirement being to **display a column value from two rows(or rows with same node_no) into a single row as two different columns**.
The order has to be maintained.

Note: This may appear like duplicate of
[SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)
[SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

But there we are displaying values as a single aggregated column.

Comment: You need to define the business logic needed more clearly.  For example, how do you determine which column `001` goes in to?  It it because it is smaller than `007` or because it's `order` values is the lowest?  What should happen is a node has more than two values?  etc, etc, etc...

Comment: It is based on `order' field, sequential.
node will not have more than two values, only 1 or max 2
Thx for the follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as 
(select node_no, code, value1,
row_number() over (partition by node_no order by order) rn
from tbl)

select a.node_no, a.code, a.value1 x, b.value1 value2 
from
cte a
left join cte b on a.node_no = b.node_no
and b.rn = 2
and a.rn = 1
where a.rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1560b/2)

Note that this assumes that your `value1` field is `varchar2`, so if you want to do some custom sorting other than the standard lexicographical one, you need to implement it yourself in the `order by` clause.

Another solution, suggested below in comments by @MatBailie removes the need for joins (the CTE is still needed):

```
SELECT node_no, 
MAX(code) as code, 
MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN value1 END) AS value1, 
MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN value1 END) AS value2 
FROM cte 
GROUP BY node_no
```

Comment: You don't need to use a join...   `SELECT node_no, MAX(code) as code, MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN value1 END) AS value1, MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN value2 END) AS value2 FROM cte GROUP BY node_no`  This will reduce both the number of reads and number of cpu cycles by not needing to process the data twice.  *(Also, by having `b.rn=2` in the WHERE clause, you've broken your LEFT JOIN and turned it in to an INNER JOIN; because if it's not present in the join the value will be NULL which is never equal to 2.)*

Comment: @MatBailie You are right, the `WHERE` does indeed change the meaning. Should I edit my answer with your suggestions, or would that be like stealing your credit?

Comment: @MatBailie My understanding is that since a `node_no` can have 2 rows, a row with `rn` = 1 must always exist in the result if it exists in input. So, the join specifies `a.rn = 1 and b.rn = 2` and an additional `where` gets only the first row from each `node_no`. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you `PARTITION BY` a column, the `ORDER BY` clause doesn't have to include that column.

Comment: Always feel free to "steal credit" from people that haven't written their own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Oracle also support the `PIVOT` clause.  You still have to get a constant column-identifier, though:

```
SELECT node_no, code, value1, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY node_no ORDER BY ordering) rn
 FROM <table_name_here>)
```

(I renamed `order` to `ordering`, as the former is a reserved word, and needs to be escaped/should be avoided if possible)
...will, as in @Shree's answer, number all rows based on the node.  This means we have a constant value per-section:

```
node_no   code   value1  order  rn
100       AB     001     1      1
100       AB     007     2      2
101       AB     010     3      1
```

At this point, it turns into a standard `PIVOT` query:

```
SELECT node_no, code, value1, value2
FROM (SELECT node_no, code, value1, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY node_no ORDER BY ordering) rn
      FROM Pivot_Example) Indexed
PIVOT (MAX(value1) FOR (rn) IN (1 AS value1, 2 AS value2))
ORDER BY node_no
```

(`PIVOT` requires an aggregate function, but in this case we don't have anything to aggregate, so...)

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e00d/4/0)</kbd>

I'm not sure if this will be more efficient than the existing answer, though.

Comment: Whoa, so Oracle `PIVOT` syntax is pretty much the same as SQL Server. Should have tried that straight away :D