# Oracle SQL 'select' with 1 column having combined values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, left-join

Table t1:

```
pk_id | col1 | col2 | col3
===========================
1     | val1 | val2 | val3
```

Table t2: (fk_id is foreign key references to pk_id)

```
fk_id | col4
=============
1     | val4A
1     | val4B
1     | val4C
```

My SQL query is:

```
select pk_id,col1,col2,col3,col4
from t1 left join t2 on t1.pk_id=t2.fk_id;
```

The result is:

```
pk_id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
===================================
1     | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4A
1     | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4B
1     | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4C
```

But I actually want this result:

```
pk_id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
===============================================
1     | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4A;val4B;val4C
```

How to change the 'select' query to achieve this result with col4 value is the combined values of val4A, val4B, val4C (separated by semicolons)?

Comment: At your position I would create a function that returns `varchar2` which wold be aggregation of the right values from 2nd table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Comment: What is your DB Version??

Comment: How about LISTAGG? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - well, I need to use `LISTAGG` more, I keep forgetting about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LISTAGG` for that.

```
select pk_id,col1,col2,col3,
                    LISTAGG (t2.col4, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.col4) AS col4
from t1 left join t2 on t1.pk_id=t2.fk_id
group by pk_id, col1, col2, col3;
```

Comment: error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Ah, sorry for that, I added the group by clause.