# adding columns and returning consolidated data

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone assist me with writing SQL query to calculate/display the following example:

**table** - ***shipment***

**columns** - ***product code  /  qty   /  unique code***

```
          sku a   |    5   | nnnn
          sku a   |    5   | nn
          sku a   |    10  | (blank)
          sku b   |    2   | nnn
          sku c   |    2   | (blank)
          sku c   |    2   | (blank)
```

I'm looking for an output like this:

**columns** - ***product code  /  qty   /  unique code***

```
          sku a   |    20   | nnnn, nn
          sku b   |    2    | nnn
          sku c   |    4    | (blank)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LISTAGG is your saviour here.

```
SELECT 
  product_code, 
  SUM(qty) as total_qty, 
  LISTAGG(unique_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY unique_code)
FROM
  shipment
GROUP BY
  product_code
```

EDIT:
Putting the answer here for the better code output:

You have "i." in front of the fields in your listagg, but you have no table aliases. Also, you need to add pallet_id to the group by. Try this

```
SELECT 
  reference_id, 
  pallet_id, 
  SUM(update_qty) as total_qty, 
  LISTAGG(user_def_type_1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_def_type_1)
FROM
  inventory_transaction 
WHERE
  code = 'Shipment' AND site_id = 'GBRUN2A' AND client_id = '021' AND dstamp >= current_date -21 
GROUP BY 
  reference_id, pallet_id
```

If you are still getting an error, can you confirm you are on Oracle? I'm pretty sure it's an Oracle-only function.

Yes - Using Oracle Sql Developer version 4.0.1.14

ETA: Can you confirm which version of Oracle Database you are running. Listagg is only on Oracle 12c and Oracle 11g Release 2. If you are running a previous version, have a look [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) for some alternate ideas.

Comment: so applying your fix to a slightly different table, i get an error...    my query -                                                                                                 SELECT
  reference_id,
  pallet_id,
  SUM(update_qty) as total qty,
  LISTAGG (user_def_type_1, ',') within group (order by user_def_type_1)
FROM
  inventory_transaction 

GROUP BY
  reference_id

Comment: the error message is as follows -                                                                        ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:   
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 28

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of Oracle that doesn't support `LISTAGG()` (e.g., Oracle 10g), then there are a couple of things you can do. The easiest is to use the undocumented `WM_CONCAT()` function (which returns either a `VARCHAR` or a `CLOB` depending on the release):

```
SELECT reference_id, pallet_id, SUM(update_qty) as total qty
     , WM_CONCAT(user_def_type_1)
  FROM inventory_transaction
 GROUP BY reference_id
```

One difficulty with using `WM_CONCAT()` is that the results of the concatenation won't be ordered. You also have no choice about your delimiter. Another option, probably a better one, is to use `XMLAGG()` (this is actually a documented function):

```
SELECT reference_id, pallet_id, SUM(update_qty) as total qty
     , XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, user_def_type_1 || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
  FROM inventory_transaction
 GROUP BY reference_id;
```

Here you have your choice of delimiters, *and* `XMLAGG()` supports an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT reference_id, pallet_id, SUM(update_qty) as total qty
     , XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, user_def_type_1 || ',') ORDER BY user_def_type_1).EXTRACT('//text()')
  FROM inventory_transaction
 GROUP BY reference_id;
```

You can find other options at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle).