# XML in T-SQL being translated to Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I couldn't get any results when I searched `XML Oracle` so hopefully we get some good insight here. I've got the following `T-SQL`:

```
( 
    SELECT ' ' + mpi.CpeValue
    FROM dbo.MitigationPatchInfo mpi
    WHERE mpi.MitigationPatchId = mp.Id
        AND mpi.InfoType = 'prereq'
    FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('CPE'), TYPE
).value('/CPE[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

I'm not sure what this is doing. Can someone break this down a little bit and/or offer a PL-SQL equivalent?

Cheers guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: This is one of the techniques used to aggregate strings, similar to MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT. There are several duplicate questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle) that mentions LISTAGG for 11g or ... XMLAGG for previous versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain this:

We have the query

```
SELECT ( 
    SELECT ' ' + mpi.CpeValue
    FROM dbo.MitigationPatchInfo mpi
    WHERE mpi.MitigationPatchId = mp.Id
        AND mpi.InfoType = 'prereq'
    FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('CPE'), TYPE
).value('/CPE[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

Lets look at the inner SELECT statement first:

```
SELECT ' ' + mpi.CpeValue
FROM dbo.MitigationPatchInfo mpi
WHERE mpi.MitigationPatchId = mp.Id
    AND mpi.InfoType = 'prereq'
```

This is a standard SELECT statement with a WHERE clause. Then we have the conversion into XML:

```
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('CPE'), TYPE
```

The `FOR XML`  retrieves formal results of the `SELECT` query as XML

The `PATH ('')` specifies the name of the child elements within the parent tag in this case since we pass an empty string there are no child elements within the parent `<CPE></CPE>` tag.
For example then we whould have something like this where the results are concatinated:

```
<CPE>reulst1result2result3</CPE>
```

if we had specified the `PATH` as `PATH('x')` for example then we would have something like this:

```
<CPE>
  <x>reulst1</x>
  <x>result2</x>
  <x>result3</x> 
</CPE>
```

The `ROOT('CPE')` specifies the name of the root tag `<CPE></CPE>`

The `.value('/CPE[1]', 'varchar(max)')` part of the query will return the value within the 1st element of the XML as a string of the type `varchar(max)`.

so the results `<CPE>reulst1result2result3</CPE>` will be returned as `reulst1result2result3`

I hope this helps. So in essence it is a very round about way of doing a simple concatenation in my view butI'm just guessing here without knowing the values within your table.

Comment: This isn't concatenation. It's one of the techniquest used to aggregate strings, similar to MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interesting. I don't really have any MySQL background. I would be more interested in learning about it.

Comment: If you search for string aggregation on SQL Server you'll find many techniques, including this one and SQLCLR.

Comment: Thanks, dude. This helped a lot.