# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected while using listagg

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT
                m.externalmerchantid AS merchant_merchantID,
                m.legalname,
                m.tradingname,
                m.status AS merchant_status,
                s.subscriptiontype AS subscriptiontype,
                s.externalid                         AS subscription_merchantID,
                s.status                             AS subscription_status,
                s.wayofintegration,
                psp.name,
                s.startdate,
                s.firstactivationdate,
                s.enddate,
                sb.iban,
                sb.sepacreditorid,
        listagg(sst.subschemetypeid, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.subscriptionid)
        FROM
                msm_merchant m,
                msm_subscription s,
                msm_subscription_bvn sb,
                psp_serviceprovider psp,
        msm_subscriptionschemetype sst
            WHERE
      s.status = 'ACTIVE'
            AND m.merchantid = s.merchant_merchantid
            AND s.subscriptionid = sb.subscriptionid
            AND m.status = 'ACTIVE'
      AND sst.subscriptionid = s.subscriptionid
            AND m.acquirer_acquirerid = 'RaboNL'
            AND s.serviceprovider_providerid = psp.serviceproviderid;
```

But Getting error

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 50
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this on Oracle 11gR1 (11.1) or earlier?

Comment: I'm trying this on oracle 10g

Comment: Alex means "Oracle 10g"; in fact, is your Oracle version 11.1 or below? LISTAGG was introduced in Oracle 11.2. FYI, I loaded your query in SQL Developer (on top of 11.2) and I see no errors.

Comment: OK, then Alex answered your question. LISTAGG doesn't exist in 10g.

Comment: Thanks :). That makes sense. Do you know a substitute for this that can run on 10 g.

Comment: [There are options here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/266304), along with a link to an often-cited article listing techniques. Not sure if the question counts as a duplicate though.