# Recursive records oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, recursive-query

I'm currently trying to create a report using SQL Developer.
     I have these 2 tables: 
 `PERSONS (IDPerson, NamePerson)
PENALTIES (IDPenalty, DatePenalty, Description, IDPerson)` 
The tables are polulated.

How could I create a table like

[image: THIS]

using recursive queries in SQL? or it's there any other solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle).

Comment: Agreed - an almost exact duplicate. The other question didn't need the join to retrieve the "name" associated with the id, but that is a separate and different kind of question (vs. the list aggregation question which is the main topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   p.nameperson as name, p.idperson as id,
         listagg(to_date(x.datepenalty, 'dd/mm/yyyy') || ' - ' || x.description, '; ')
                                      within group (order by x.datepenalty) as penalties
from     persons p left outer join penalties x
                   on p.idperson = x.idperson
group by p.idperson;
```

(Not tested - you didn't provide test data.)