# DB ORACLE QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have a table where storing details

```
ID     NAME
1       A
2       A
1       A
```

I need the output like

```
ID     Name   Count
1,2     A      3
```

Please help to get the output like that in oracle select query

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Also, please tell us which version of Oracle you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+oracle

Comment: Oracle 11 we are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `listagg()`, but it has no `distinct` option.  So, use a subquery and two levels of aggregation:

```
select listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as id, name, sum(cnt)
from (select id, name, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id, name
     ) x
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the support