# Oracle Select Query with JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below Oracle SQL Query and it works fine

```
 Select Cage.BARCODE Cg, CagePen.BARCODE Pen
 FROM LOCATION_ENTITY CagePen
 LEFT JOIN LOCATION_ENTITY Cage ON SUBSTR(CagePen.FULL_LOCATION, -6)=Cage.BARCODE
 WHERE CagePen.FULL_LOCATION = 'Current'
```

I get the response back like

```
      CG    PEN
  CGE100    CP4265
  CGE100    CP4264
  CGE101    CP4266
  CGE101    CP4267
  CGE102    CP4268
  CGE102    CP4269
```

Now I am trying to consolidate the response where CG is repeated

```
   CG            PEN
 CGE100   CP4265,   CP4264
 CGE101   CP4266,   CP4267
 CGE102   CP4268,   CP4269
```

Should this query be using `agg()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: Looks like the question is not really about the joins but about aggregating the results into a comma-separated format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `listagg()`

```
SELECT Cage.BARCODE as Cg, LISTAGG(CagePen.BARCODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CagePen.BARCODE) as Pens
FROM LOCATION_ENTITY CagePen LEFT JOIN
     LOCATION_ENTITY Cage 
     ON SUBSTR(CagePen.FULL_LOCATION, -6) = Cage.BARCODE
WHERE CagePen.FULL_LOCATION = 'Current'
GROUP BY Cage.BARCODE;
```