# concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, string-concatenation, listagg

I can [concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle) using `LISTAGG`

But I want to avoid duplicates

Currently it return duplicates

```
select LISTAGG( t.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.id) from table t;
```

for example for data

```
ID
10
10
20
30
30
40
```

Returns `10,10,20,30,40,40`

Instead `10,20,30,40`

And I can't use `distinct` inside `LISTAGG`

```
select LISTAGG( distinct t.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.id) from table t;
```

Error

```
ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(
                      listagg( t.id,',') within group (order by t.id)
                      , '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') as "Result"
  from t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=47472b164889bb2899d44a6e6aca3cae)</kbd>

Comment: This does not work in all cases:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5f41fe131e9cc094f75c40b3b652a30a.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the distinct in a subquery:

```sql
select LISTAGG( t.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.id) from (SELECT DISTINCT t.id FROM TABLE) t
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, It's part of complex query and I wonder if I can do it without another subquery?