# How to output multi data per column in one row?

Tags: sql

I have data as follows: We call this table Client_benefits

```
Client_name, Income_type, Frequency
Joe Smith SSI Month
Joe Smith Work Week
```

I would like an out put row as follows: I would like something like

```
Select Client_name, Income_type, Frequency from Client_benefits
```

Do I use grouo_by?

To create the singular per client output I need?

Joe Smith SSI Month Work Week

Rather than currently I am getting duplicates but would like to see one row if possible.

Comment: have you tried using distinct?

Comment: What's the exact expected result according to your sample data?

Comment: Joe Smith SSI Month Work Week
evreything on one row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: Maybe but it's Oracle.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. You want output similar to:

```
Joe Smith "SSI Month" "Work Week"
```

It is doubtful that you will be able to segregate these into their own columns, but you can concatenate them into a single field.

That question has already been asked and answered here:

[SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/2657515)

Comment: that's an Oracle syntax so I am not sure about this. Usually there is syntax differences to the extent you cannot rely on using Oracle code in a SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as:

```
 SELECT Client_name+ ' ' +  
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Income_type + ' ' + Frequency
           FROM Client_benefits CBIn 
           WHERE CBIn.Client_name = CBOut.Client_name 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Client_benefits CBOut
GROUP BY Client_name
```

[SQL Demo here..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ec19/1)

Comment: HI this idea means entry to a table. I am looking for a dynamic query.