# Multiple row data in single row as comma separated (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

How to make select statement where result is rows combined in comma separated manner based on columns (user & group).

[image]

Expected result

```
USER | GROUP | SUB
-------------------------
3    | 102   | 1,3,2,4,61
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `LISTAGG` was built for

```sql
  SELECT t.USER, t.group, LISTAGG (t.sub, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.pk_id)
    FROM your_table t
GROUP BY t.USER, t.GROUP
```