# How to use listagg function in select query?

Tags: oracle19c

I want to use the listagg function in select query of a view. So the following is sample data of that view:

| id | name | last name | contacts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | khan | 111 |
| 1 | john | khan | 222 |
| 1 | john | khan | 333 |
| 2 | smith | mike | 55 |
| 2 | smith | mike | 66 |

The expected result which I want is:

| id | name | last name | contacts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | khan | 111,222,333 |
| 2 | smith | mike | 55,66 |

Comment: The below link can help you solve your problem,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Comment: If you already know you need to use [`listagg()`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi8kqq39975AhWFS8AKHXNDDOYQFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fen%2Fdatabase%2Foracle%2Foracle-database%2F19%2Fsqlrf%2FLISTAGG.html&usg=AOvVaw04MetIL3aiX7N_K2Aoi6gQ), what is the problem? If you have written a query that gets an error or doesn't get the result you expect then include that - and the outcome - in your question.