# LISTAGG in oracle claims a right parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm trying to list in one row using LISTAGG in Oracle, but I get the "Right Parameter" error and I don't know why.

Here is my SQL command:

```
SELECT listagg (ODA_CdiDispositivoAcesso, ';')
    FROM DispositivosAcessosOcors
    INNER JOIN DispositivosAcessos ON (ODA_CdiDispositivoAcesso = DIS_CdiDispositivoAcesso)
    WHERE ODA_CdiTpOcorrenciaDispositivo in (500)
    and DIS_OplDesativado = 0
    and ODA_DtdInicio <= sysdate
    and (ODA_DtdFim is null or ODA_dtdFim >= sysdate)
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? The code as shown would throw "ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword", not what I presume you are seeing, "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". But I think you would get that error on versions before 11gR2, where `listagg()` was introduced. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/266304) may be helpful.)

Comment: I'm using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0 here. Would work, right?

Comment: Yes... so what is the actual full error message you are getting? "Right Parameter" isn't an Oracle error, and you shouldn't be getting ORA-00907 which seemed a likely option. Please include the full error message, including the ORA code if there is one; and if there isn't, which client are you running this in?

Comment: Hello Alex, sorry for delay.

Below the complete message:

`ORA-01489: o resultado da concatenação de string é extenso demais
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.`

There's a sentence in portuguese that's the same in the "cause" line.

Comment: I don't know how you got from there to "right parameter", but that's a common error... as you're on 19c look at the [overflow clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html).

Answer (score 4):

The [`LISTAGG` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) is `LISTAGG(column_name [, delimiter]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)`; you have missed the end of the command.

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(ODA_CdiDispositivoAcesso, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ODA_CdiDispositivoAcesso)
FROM DispositivosAcessosOcors
     INNER JOIN DispositivosAcessos
     ON (ODA_CdiDispositivoAcesso = DIS_CdiDispositivoAcesso)
WHERE ODA_CdiTpOcorrenciaDispositivo in (500)
and   DIS_OplDesativado = 0
and   ODA_DtdInicio <= sysdate
and   (ODA_DtdFim is null or ODA_dtdFim >= sysdate)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/868_BJHm)

Comment: `within group` is optional since 18c and there's no any "right parameter" error in Oracle. The code in question is valid for 18c and above: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mEsptQJ2)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Oracle 19c and I've tried with the "within" but doesn't work too