# Left Outer JOIN with no multiple records of left table

Tags: database, oracle, join, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper

A[id, name]

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | name1 |
| 1002 | name2 |

B[id, productId, serviceId].

| id | productId | serviceId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | p1 | s1 |
| 1001 | p1 | s2 |
| 1001 | p2 | s2 |
| 1004 | p1 | s2 |

One id in B can have many products & many services.
(A product can have many services and a service can have many products.)

My goal is get every id from table A with its associated products and services. But I should not get multiple id rows.

Left Outer join is giving me multiple rows of same ids.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, B.PRODUCTID, B.SERVICEID
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE some conditions ;
```

Comment: Aggregate them. Append `GROUP BY a.id` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine all products and services together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Issues here are faqs.  Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: above question didn't exactly answer my question because I couldn't aggregate products and services properly to get unique ids after join too.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But that comment is not clear--why "because". Any again: when you pin down each place you get what you don't expect it will be a faq. The given link explains how joins work, and your post doesn't ask a clear question about join. Please act on the comments. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/3404097) "google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal" etc. There isn't even a question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```sql
SELECT ID, A_NAME, MAX(LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) "LIST_OF_PRODUCTS", MAX(LIST_OF_SERVICES) "LIST_OF_SERVICES"
FROM    
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
                ID, A_NAME, 
                LISTAGG(CASE WHEN P_ID_RN = 1 THEN PRODUCT_ID END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By PRODUCT_ID) OVER(Partition By ID) "LIST_OF_PRODUCTS",
                LISTAGG(CASE WHEN S_ID_RN = 1 THEN SERVICE_ID END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By SERVICE_ID) OVER(Partition By ID) "LIST_OF_SERVICES"
        FROM
            (  SELECT  
                          a.ID, a.A_NAME,
                          b.PRODUCT_ID,
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By a.ID, b.PRODUCT_ID Order By PRODUCT_ID) "P_ID_RN",
                          b.SERVICE_ID,
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By a.ID, b.PRODUCT_ID, b.SERVICE_ID Order By b.PRODUCT_ID) "S_ID_RN"
                FROM      tbl_a a
                LEFT JOIN tbl_b b ON (a.ID = b.ID) 
            )
    )
WHERE     LIST_OF_PRODUCTS Is Not Null OR LIST_OF_SERVICES Is Not Null
GROUP BY  ID, A_NAME
ORDER BY  ID
```

... which with sample data as below ...

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a AS
        (
            Select 1001 "ID", 'Name 1' "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 1002 "ID", 'Name 2' "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 1003 "ID", 'Name 3' "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 1004 "ID", 'Name 4' "A_NAME" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_b AS
        (
            Select 1001 "ID", 'P_1' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_1' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1001 "ID", 'P_1' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_2' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1001 "ID", 'P_1' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_5' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1002 "ID", 'P_4' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_1' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1002 "ID", 'P_4' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_3' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1003 "ID", 'P_2' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_1' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1003 "ID", 'P_3' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_2' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 1004 "ID", 'P_1' "PRODUCT_ID", 'S_2' "SERVICE_ID" From Dual 
        )
```

... results:

| ID | A_NAME | LIST_OF_PRODUCTS | LIST_OF_SERVICES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Name 1 | P_1 | S_1, S_2, S_5 |
| 1002 | Name 2 | P_4 | S_1, S_3 |
| 1003 | Name 3 | P_2, P_3 | S_1, S_2 |
| 1004 | Name 4 | P_1 | S_2 |

Comment: This is just way to complicated --- and it must be so slow.  Two left joins with distinct solve it better

Comment: @Hogan Your answer is repeating the same value (my sample data with your answer for ID 1001 results as PRODUCTS = P_1, P_1, P_1 ).  You have the same issue with SERVICES too. The quqestion is explicite - no repetings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use `LISTAGG(DISTINCT...`  in Oracle (you can in DB and SQL Server) your query you can do the following to solve the issue of multiple items in the list:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME,
 LISTAGG(P.PRODUCTID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.PRODUCTID) "PRODUCTS",
 LISTAGG(S.SERVICEID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S.SERVICEID) "SERVICES"
FROM TABLE_A A 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, PRODUCTID
  FROM TABLE_B
) AS P ON A.ID = P.ID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, SERVICEID
  FROM TABLE_B
) AS S ON A.ID = S.ID 
WHERE some conditions
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME;
```